# How to setup client side metadata for SPA using breeze

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Hello all I am working on a small report library SPA using angular and breeze that allows a user to manage reports they create.  I know you can use breeze along with the EF context to build the model by referencing the API.. But how this is being implemented I want to leave EF out of it. The API (WebAPI 2) is basically calling other repositories to do the work almost like an interface. The result coming back is just a json object.  I have looked over the Edmunds sample from the Breeze website and I can see how I can build a client model as well as handle the mapping on the return. The current issue I have is I am not certain that I have the mapping in the jsonResultsAdapter correct. Or that I may be missing something on how the mapping is supposed to work.

I'm testing this currently with some mock data I have stubbed into the API until I can get this to work. Once this is bound and mapping I can go against the actual data. Here is what I have so far:
The mock data is a report object that contains an internal collection called labels (tags basically) a report can have multiple tag and from the label it can have multiple reports.

```
//report dto
public class ReportDto
{

    public Int64 ReportId { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public string ReportDescription { get; set; }
    public string ReportDateCreated { get; set; }
    public string ReportOwner { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReportLabelDto> ReportLabels { get; set; } 
}

public class ReportLabelDto
{
    public Int64 LabelId { get; set; }
    public string LabelName { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReportDto> Reports { get; set; }//placeholder?
}
```

Here is the code currently being used within the webapi controller which at this time is just for testing:

```
[Route ("reportlibrary/myreports/{userid}")]
public IEnumerable<ReportDto> GetAllReports(string userId)
{
    List<ReportDto> result = new List<ReportDto>();
    List<ReportLabelDto> label = new List<ReportLabelDto>();
    //create 5 reports
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ReportDto r = new ReportDto();
        ReportLabelDto l = new ReportLabelDto();

        r.ReportId = i;
        r.ReportOwner = "John Smith";
        r.ReportDateCreated = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        r.ReportDescription = "Report Description # " + i.ToString();
        r.ReportName = "Report Description # " + i.ToString();        
        //generate labels
        l.LabelId = i;
        l.LabelName = "Special Label" + i.ToString();
        l.IsPrivate = true;
        l.IsFavorite = false;
        label.Add(l);
        r.ReportLabels = label;
        result.Add(r);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The object that is currently coming back looks like this:

```
[{"ReportId":0,"ReportName":"Report Description # 0","ReportDescription":"Report Description # 0","ReportDateCreated":"12/22/2014 6:32:05 PM","ReportOwner":"John Smith","ReportLabels":[{"LabelId":0,"LabelName":"Special Label0","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null},{"LabelId":1,"LabelName":"Special Label1","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null},{"LabelId":2,"LabelName":"Special Label2","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null},{"LabelId":3,"LabelName":"Special Label3","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null},{"LabelId":4,"LabelName":"Special Label4","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null}]},{"ReportId":1,"ReportName":"Report Description # 1","ReportDescription":"Report Description # 1","ReportDateCreated":"12/22/2014 6:32:05 PM","ReportOwner":"John Smith","ReportLabels":[{"LabelId":0,"LabelName":"Special Label0","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null},{"LabelId":1,"LabelName":"Special Label1","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null},{"LabelId":2,"LabelName":"Special Label2","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null},{"LabelId":3,"LabelName":"Special Label3","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null},{"LabelId":4,"LabelName":"Special Label4","IsPrivate":true,"IsFavorite":false,"Reports":null}]},...]
```

I have the services and controllers all talking and I can hit the api and get an object returned so I am going to omit that code for right now.

For the js model I defined the report object as follows:

```
app.factory('model', function () {

    var DT = breeze.DataType;
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    }

    function initialize(metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: "Report",
            namespace: "Inform",
            dataProperties: {
                reportid: { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
                reportname: { dataType: DT.String },
                reportdescription: { dataType: DT.String },
                reportdatecreated: { dataType: DT.String },
                reportowner: { dataType: DT.String },
                mappedlabels: { dataType: DT.Undefined },
                ishared: { dataType: DT.Bool },
                isfavorite: { dataType: DT.Bool }
            },
            navigationProperties: {
                labels: {
                    entityTypeName: "Label:#Inform", isScalar: false,
                    associationName: "Report_Labels"
                }
            }
        });
        metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: "Label",
            namespace: "Inform",
            dataProperties: {
                labelid: { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
                reportid: { dataType: DT.Int64 },
                labelname: { dataType: DT.String },
                ispublic: { dataType: DT.Bool },
                mappedreports: { dataType: DT.Undefined }
            },
            navigationProperties: {
                labels: {
                    entityTypeName: "Report:#Inform", isScalar: false,
                    associationName: "Report_Labels", foreignKeyNames: ["reportid"]
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
```

This is where I think the issue is I don't understand this adapter enough to ensure that I am receiving what I think I am as well as if it is handling the mapping correctly:

```
/* jsonResultsAdapter: parses report data into entities */
app.value('jsonResultsAdapter',
    new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({

        name: "inform",

        extractResults: function (data) {
            var results = data.results;
            if (!results) throw new Error("Unable to resolve 'results' property");
            // Parse only the make and model types
            return results && (results.reportHolder || results.labelHolder);
        },

        visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {
            //Report parser
            if (node.reportid && node.labels) {

                node.mappedlabels = node.labels;
                node.labels = [];
                return { entityType: "Report" }
            }

            // Label parser
            else if (node.labelid && node.reports) {

                node.mappedreports = node.reports;
                node.mappedreports = [];
                return { entityType: "Label" };
            }
        }

    }));
```

When I step through the code in chrome I can see that an object is returned. with 5 reports and each report has 5 labels ( I know the labels are showing null reports currently). When I set breakpoints within the jsonResultsAdapter I can see the result with 5 objects, but what gets passed back to the service is as a result is null. Can anyone help me verify if the model and mapping is correct or if you see anything out of place in the jsonResultsAdapter. I'd also appreciate any suggestions on things I may want to do different. I feel very black-box right now as I don't see/understand a good way to troubleshoot this mapping piece.

-cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'll pick up on some of PW Kad's observations and add a few of my own.

Let's first understand the different roles of metadata and the `JsonResultsAdapter`.

**Metadata** is where you define the schema and validation rules for the client-side entity model. It describes the entity objects that Breeze keeps in cache and makes available to your program.

But the metadata have nothing to say about the JSON payload arriving from the server. That's a completely separate and lower level concern. That's the concern of the `JsonResultsAdapter`.

The **`JsonResultsAdapter`** sits in the pipeline between the JSON data arriving from the server as a result of an AJAX call ... and the entities in cache. The JSON data don't have to be shaped like the entities. They don't have to conform to the metadata you wrote. The metadata describe *the entities as you would like to consume them*.  The JSON are the sad reality that the service gives you. The `JsonResultsAdapter` is there to bridge the gap.

Whether the entity schema conforms to the shape of the JSON payload is anyone's guess. Often the JSON data needs a little tweaking. It's the `JsonResultsAdapter`'s job to manipulate the JSON "nodes" into something that Breeze can map into your entities. The job is easier if the JSON payload closely approximates the entity shape described by your metadata. Let's hope your JSON aligns well with your entities.

### Metadata and materialization

Now Breeze does use the metadata when mapping the JSON into the entities. The `MetadataStore` has a `NamingConvention` that prescribes how to translate between the client entity property names and the service property names. The "materialization" process expects the JSON emerging from the `JsonResultsAdapter` to have the expected service property names. That's why I was adamant that the node property names (if you need them) be spelled in PascalCase ... assuming that you are using the standard Breeze camelCase convention  and that your service does, in fact, spell property names in PascalCase.

> Most C# and Java servers do. Rails and Node servers generally don't; they use camelCase on the server too ... which means you'd want `NamingConvention.none` if you're consuming feeds from these kinds of servers.

Ideally the `JsonResultsAdapter` has to do very little. The JSON property names typically map easily and obviously to the entity property names and you can handle whatever translation is needed with a `NamingConvention`.  Such appears to be the case for you (see below).

For sure you're not accomplishing a thing with the code you showed us:

```
node.ReportId = node.ReportId;
node.ReportName = node.ReportName;
node.ReportDescription = node.ReportDescription;
```

That is the most elaborate "no op" code I've seen in a very long time. I wonder what you had in mind.

`JsonResultsAdapter` is often needed **when identifying the EntityType corresponding to a JSON node**.  If you're not sourcing the data from .NET using the Json.Net serializer, your server may not be sending the type name down with the JSON data. Your JSON nodes are missing the `$type` property that Breeze is looking for by default.

If that's your situation (and it seems it is), your `JsonResultsAdapter` has to supply the type name.

Apparently, you can do that for your data by examining each node's key property. It seems that key property name contains within itself the distinguishing part of the type name.

Perhaps your `JsonResultsAdapter.visitNode` method could look like this:

```
visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {
    //Report parser
    if (node.ReportId) {
        return { entityType: "Report:#Inform" }
    }
    // Label entity
    else if (node.ReportLabels) {
        return { entityType: "Label:#Inform" };
    }
}
```

Notice that I **included the *namespace* (`:#Inform`) in the `entityType` name property**. The namespace is part of each EntityType's full name ... and you must supply it.

Notice that I did NOT do any property name mapping. I didn't see any reason for it. The node property  names look just like the entity metadata names ... except for the PascalCasing ... and we take care of that with the `NamingConvention.camelCase`.

### Bad Metadata?

Well actually the node property names **do NOT** look like the entity property names in your metadata, not even after accounting for the Pascal-to-camel-case conversion. I think this is what PW Kad was pointing out.

The problem is that the entity property names in your metadata are **all lower case**. Not camelCase; lower case. For example:

```
reportid: { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
reportname: { dataType: DT.String },
reportdescription: ...
```

Shouldn't they be:

```
reportId: { dataType: DT.Int64, isPartOfKey: true },
reportName: { dataType: DT.String },
reportDescription: ...
```

That would correspond nicely to your JSON property names

```
ReportId
ReportName 
ReportDescription
```

Why would you want all lowercase property names on the client.

> You could go all lowercase and write a really wacky custom `NamingConvention` to navigate between client entity names and service names. That's a lot of work to no purpose in my book.

### Why is there no $type in your JSON?

I just scrolled to the top of this question and realized that your server is written in C# and it looks like you're using the Web API.

Why did you not annotate your Web API controller with the `[BreezeController]` attribute? Doing so would have configured your controller to serialize the data in the manner a Breeze client understands by default. You might not need a `JsonResultsAdapter` at all.

### Don't change the type name!

Looking again I see yet another problem looming ahead. Your server-side class names have the suffix "Dto" but you don't want that suffix on your client type names. You are also changing the type name completely in one case: "ReportLabelDto"  to "Label".

Breeze has a naming convention for morphing *property* names. It doesn't have a naming convention for  "entity type" names.

It will be a royal pain if you insist on having different type names on the client and the server. I'm not sure it can be done.

Yes you can morph the entity name in the `JsonResultsAdapter`. That covers communications *on the way **in***. But you also have to worry about the communications *on the way **out***. The server is not going to be happy when you ask it to save an entity of class "Label" ... which it knows nothing about.

As I write I can't think of an easy way around this. At the moment, Breeze requires that the server-side type name be the same as the client EntityType name. If the type name on the server is "ReportLabelDto", you'll have to name the corresponding EntityType "ReportLabelDto". There is no easy way around that.

Fortunately, unlike property names which show up everywhere, you don't often refer to the EntityType name on the client so calling it "ReportLabelDto" shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: WOW! thanks for taking the time to clarify how all this works! An amazing explanation. I greatly appreciate you taking the time. I;m obviously still learning Angular and Breeze was recently thrown onto the stack and I am admittedly fumbling around. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all of your properties you are defining are not properly camelCased nor PascalCased.  Breeze.js will look for properties that match - but unless I am missing something you have defined it will not toLowerCase them.

You need to set your model properties up like this -

```
ReportName: { dataType: DT.String },
```

and then in your results adapter you need to check for the property names properly like this -

```
if (node.ReportId && node.Labels) {
```

Comment: @rlcrews properties in c# are PascalCase and camelCase in js/json by convention. The json.NET library has an option to convert the property case for you at serialization. It handles to conversion back at deserialization as well.

Comment: Yes the json.NET serializer does have such an option ... and **you must NOT use it w/ Breeze!** See [explanation here](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/naming-convention)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to PW Kad for pointing me in the right direction. I had forgotten the case sensitivity portion. In addition I went back and reassessed what I was trying to do in the `jsonResultsAdapter.js` file. I finally realized this file is working similar to automapper and I was under the impression that breeze would internally resolve the mappings. (maybe it does but with the EF context) but when creating client side meta I had to explicitly set the mappings. The updated code now shows:

```
app.value('jsonResultsAdapter',
    new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({

        name: "inform",

        extractResults: function (data) {
            var results = data.results;
            if (!results) throw new Error("Unable to resolve 'results' property");
            // Parse only the make and model types
            return results;
        },

        visitNode: function (node, parseContext, nodeContext) {
            //Report parser
            if (node) {

                node.ReportId = node.ReportId;
                node.ReportName = node.ReportName;
                node.ReportDescription = node.ReportDescription;
                node.ReportDateCreated = node.ReportDateCreated;
                node.ReportOwner = node.ReportOwner;
                node.ReportLabels = node.ReportLabels;
                node.ReportLabels = [];
                node.IsShared = node.IsShared;
                node.IsFavorite = node.IsFavorite;

                return { entityType: "Report" }
            }

            // Label parser
            else if (node.ReportLabels) {

                node.LabelId = node.LabelId;
                node.LabelName = nodel.LabelName;
                node.IsPrivate = node.IsPrivate;
                node.IsFavorite = node.IsFavorite;
                node.Reports = node.Reports;
                node.Reports = [];
                return { entityType: "Label" };
            }
        }

    }));
```

I know I still have some tweaking to do on the mappings more than likely or how it is parsed from the API but making this change properly mapped the mock data and allowed it to bind/display within the UI.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey just as a note you should not have to map the properties explicitly like that, essentially you are saying 'set this.labelId to this.labelId' which is already the value

Comment: PW Kad is correct. Please **DO NOT DO THAT**. Incidentally, the code as shown will never get to the second `ReportLabels` case ... because `if (node)` is always true.

Comment: FWIW, the node property values must always be the **server-side** name for the property, not the **client-side** name. So if they are  PascalCase on the server they should be PascalCase in the `visitNode` method. Breeze applies the camelCase convention downstream from here. This is **different** from the EntityType definitions you (may) write in hand-coded metadata; those should be in the target client-side spelling (e.g., camelCase).

Comment: @Ward so what is the correct definition of the meta? is it just the declaration? instead of node.ReportId = node.Reportid, should it just be node.ReportId; Sorry but I'm still not clear on exactly how this mapping works. Any additional info or samples would be appreciated.